# AngularJS component injector moduleerr

Tags: angularjs

I try to write my first component. Actually, I refactor one of my previous webpage to use more of the AngularJS functionality.
I use AngularJS 1.5.8

Honestly I always got the following inject error:
http://screencast.com/t/xpyVqSjwUxU

Here is my component code:
http://screencast.com/t/zMaED5ZfZ

The error only came up, when I add the component.js file in index.html with a script tag.

Any idea, what I'm gonna mess? I read the component angularjs documentation but not find the error.

Comment: I figured it out, the component name is the problem.
Intead of UpdatePasswordComponent I need to use the update-password name, and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the return value `{ templateUrl: ..., controller..., etc }` in the `.component()` function.

```
angular
  .module('Profile')
  .component('UpdatePasswordComponent', {
    templateUrl: '/modules/profile/update-password/update-password.component.html',
    controller: UpdatePasswordController,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to just change this line

```
.component('UpdatePasswordComponent', Component)
```

to

```
.component('UpdatePasswordComponent', Component())
```

which will actually call and return the object, but I'm not positive on this one.